# How to move an image within the header?

Tags: html, css, background-image

Header screen:

[image: Header screen]

I'd like to move it higher and to the left a little bit, but transform option moves a whole block. How can I deal with it?

CSS

```
.header {

    height: 100vh;
    width: 96%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;

    &__background {
        background-image: linear-gradient(
            to right bottom,
            rgba($color-main-green, 0.3),
            rgba($color-main-purple, 0.5)),
            url(../resources/img-cropped/header.jpg);



    }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `background-position` property to move the background image. maybe use `background-position: top left` and if this does not suit the desired results you can also add px values instead of top, left, right and bottom.

Try to experiment until you achieve the desired result.

For example: This piece of code would make the image positioned 30px from the left:

```
background-position: left 30px center;
```

The center is for the y value of the image. You could also add px values to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Use background-position, background-size and background-repeat CSS property to adjust the image.